# Coarse underlying curve of a smooth stable curve

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, moduli-spaces, gromov-witten-theory

In the theory of moduli spaces of smooth stable curves with $n$-marked points, I have come across the notion of the coarse underlying curve. Let $C$ be a smooth stable genus $g$ curve with $n$-marked point. We could give it additional structure such as an $r$-spin structure, then there is a **natural** map to the **coarse underlying curve**. How is this coarse underlying curve defined and what is this natural map? Is it related to the compactification of the Deligne-Mumford stack or is this something else?

I have not been able to find a definition in any of the papers I am reading. Can someone suggest a reference or give me an intuitive/short description of what this is?

Comment: Where did you find this notion?

Comment: @abx See for example page 3 in this paper https://arxiv.org/pdf/1710.04829.pdf and related references on r-spin closed intersection theory.

Comment: Have a look at the reference [9] in the paper you quote, you'll find a precise definition (in §2.2).

Comment: Thank you! I will check it out.